# SQLDeveloper runs query but getting a "ORA-00979: Not a Group By expression" from hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, average

I have data that looks something like this:

```
  sensorid |  sampletime             |  correctedvalue   | qualityflag
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  4472     | 27-OCT-10 00:00:00.123  |   3.75            | 0
  4472     | 27-OCT-10 00:00:01.324  |   3.85            | 0
  4472     | 27-OCT-10 00:00:02.123  |   3.92            | 0
  4472     | 27-OCT-10 00:00:03.324  |   4.05            | 0
```

And a query that works fine in Oracle SQL Developer (It returns data averaged over 15 second periods):

```
select sensorid,
    trunc(sampletime,'hh24') + 
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'ss')/15)*15)/24/60/60 as tspan, 
    avg(correctedvalue),
    max(qualityflag)
from scalarsample
group by sensorid, 
    trunc(sampletime,'hh24') + 
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'ss')/15)*15)/24/60/60
order by tspan
```

but when I plug it into my java code, I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:118)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:224)
...
```

The actual query string I use in the Jave looks more like this:

```
select sensorid,
    trunc(sampletime,'hh24') + 
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'ss')/?)*?)/24/60/60 as tspan, 
    avg(correctedvalue),
    max(qualityflag)
from scalarsample
where sampletime between ? and ?
    and sensorid = ?
group by sensorid, 
    trunc(sampletime,'hh24') + 
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'ss')/?)*?)/24/60/60
order by tspan
```

and the parameters are set by calling:

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
q.setInteger(0, averagingWindowInSeconds);
q.setInteger(1, averagingWindowInSeconds);
q.setTimestamp(2, dateFrom);
q.setTimestamp(3, dateTo);
q.setInteger(4, sensorId);
q.setInteger(5, averagingWindowInSeconds);
q.setInteger(6, averagingWindowInSeconds);
q.addEntity(ScalarSampleState.class);
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this "Not a GROUP BY expression" error?

I picked up this way of doing averaging over time intervals from Tom here:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4222062043865

**EDIT**
It almost seemed to be resolved by the following:

```
select sensorid,
    trunc(sampletime,'hh24') + 
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,'ss')/?)*?)/24/60/60 as sampletime, 
    avg(correctedvalue),
    max(qualityflag)
from scalarsample
where sampletime between ? and ?
    and sensorid = ?
group by sensorid, sampletime
order by sampletime
```

*Note:*  I used sampletime to rename the column, which is the name of one of the columns in the table.  It wouldn't work with the name "tspan" instead of sampletime:

```
ORA-00904: "TSPAN": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

When I named the new column sampletime, and used sampletime in the GROUP BY by clause, that error went away, and the query ran perfectly in SQLDeveloper.  Unfortunately, when running from Java, it returned several identical rows for each sampletime.  Grrrr....

**SOLUTION:** What did work is the chosen solution below -- I took out the quotation marks and plus signs around the string to make it more readable here:

```
SELECT
    sensorid, 
    TRUNC( sampletime, hh24) +
    (TRUNC(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (TRUNC(to_char(sampletime,'ss')//averagingWindowInSeconds )*averagingWindowInSeconds)/24/60/60 as sampletime,
    AVG( correctedvalue) as correctedvalue, 
    MAX(qualityflag)
FROM scalarsample
WHERE 
    sampletime BETWEEN ? AND ?
    AND sensorid = ?
GROUP BY sensorid,
    TRUNC( sampletime, hh24) +
    (TRUNC(to_char(sampletime,'mi')))/24/60 +
    (TRUNC(to_char(sampletime,'ss')//averagingWindowInSeconds 
ORDER BY sampletime ";
```

Comment: Это вседа так бывает не очень хороший вопрос.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, ORDER BY should only list the GROUP BY expressions. Try ORDER BY 2 or leave out ORDER BY and switch the first two SELECT columns.

Comment: Sorry, found [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm). Maybe this means that one should do `ORDER by tspan, sensorid`.

Comment: I would go with that, but it runs fine in SQL Developer.  It has something to do with Hibernate, but the error message just doesn't make sense if it's an object mapping issue.

Comment: Crazy!  @JoopEggen, that was it: I just renamed that group by expression to tspan.  Thanks!  If you write it out as an answer I'll mark that.

Comment: No need for points. Glad you found it.

Comment: @JoopEggen Uh oh.  I thought I had it, but in fact I didn't.  The data being returned to the Java code is repeated 3 times for every line.  I'll add an edit above to demonstrate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the JDBC driver is creating a unique bind variable name for each "?".  Unfortunately, in Oracle, the group by clauses must match character for character with the select clauses, and because of this, it doesn't.
I mocked up a table with your data in Oracle, and I ran a few test queries with dynamic SQL and bind variables.
First, with sequentially named bind variables:

```
SQL> l
  1  declare
  2  cur sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4  open cur for 'select sensorid, ' ||
  5  '    trunc(sampletime,''hh24'') +  ' ||
  6  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''mi'')))/24/60 + ' ||
  7  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''ss'')/:b1)*:b2)/24/60/60 as tspan,  ' ||
  8  '    avg(correctedvalue), ' ||
  9  '    max(qualityflag) ' ||
 10  'from scalarsample ' ||
 11  'where sampletime between DATE ''2010-10-27'' and DATE ''2010-10-28'' ' ||
 12  '    and sensorid = 4472 ' ||
 13  'group by sensorid,  ' ||
 14  '    trunc(sampletime,''hh24'') +  ' ||
 15  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''mi'')))/24/60 + ' ||
 16  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''ss'')/:b3)*:b4)/24/60/60 ' ||
 17  'order by tspan'
 18  using 15, 15, 15, 15;
 19  close cur;
 20* end;
```

The results:

```
SQL> @test
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Second, with the same named bind variables:

```
SQL> l
  1  declare
  2  cur sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4  open cur for 'select sensorid, ' ||
  5  '    trunc(sampletime,''hh24'') +  ' ||
  6  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''mi'')))/24/60 + ' ||
  7  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''ss'')/:b1)*:b1)/24/60/60 as tspan,  ' ||
  8  '    avg(correctedvalue), ' ||
  9  '    max(qualityflag) ' ||
 10  'from scalarsample ' ||
 11  'where sampletime between DATE ''2010-10-27'' and DATE ''2010-10-28'' ' ||
 12  '    and sensorid = 4472 ' ||
 13  'group by sensorid,  ' ||
 14  '    trunc(sampletime,''hh24'') +  ' ||
 15  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''mi'')))/24/60 + ' ||
 16  '    (trunc(to_char(sampletime,''ss'')/:b1)*:b1)/24/60/60 ' ||
 17  'order by tspan'
 18  using 15, 15, 15, 15;
 19  close cur;
 20* end;
```

The results:

```
SQL> @test
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So, try concatenating your `averagingWindowInSeconds` value to your query, instead of having those 4 bind variables.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. I seem to recall running into issues with bind variables previously. I had thought it only happened when I was using Query objects with named queries, and last time I resolved it using SQLQuery objects created with a query String.  The comment above helped resolve the problem, apparently by taking the bind variables out of the group-by phrase   Thanks for your insights!

Comment: This works.  Thanks for the excellent example and the very clear explanation as to the cause!  I concatenated the averagingWindowInSeconds into the group by clause and it works fine now.